# Absolutely stumped! Can't remove extra pixels from box

Tags: html, css

Could somebody please help remove the extra pixels under the orange box on the site:

http://www.leftright.org.au/

Somebody else setup the site and now I am trying to edit it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `display: block` to the image. I just tried that with Chrome dev tools and it worked.

`a img { display: block; }`

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `line-height` property from the below css declaration, I think it should work:

```
iframe#launch-video-frame, div#blog-contents{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your code by fixing box height equal to image height to remove extra margin under orange box as:

```
div id="blog" class="shaded box" style="height: 363px";
```

Also, the padding of 5px in `<a>` tag is displaying a blue bar when hovering on image bottom(unless you did it purposely) :)